# TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf, fpdf

I'm trying to generate pdf with the combination of TCPDF and FPDI. Here is my code.

```
require_once('../tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
require_once('../FPDI/fpdi.php');

$fileName = '../sample.pdf';

class PDF extends FPDI {
/**
 * "Remembers" the template id of the imported page
 */
var $_tplIdx;
var $numPages = 0;

/**
 * Draw an imported PDF logo on every page
 */
function Header() {

    global $fileName;

    if (is_null($this->_tplIdx)) {
        $this->setSourceFile($fileName);
        $this->_tplIdx = $this->importPage(1);
        $this->numPages = $this->setSourceFile($fileName);
    }
    $size = $this->useTemplate($this->_tplIdx);
}

function Footer() {
    // emtpy method body
}
}

// initiate PDF
$pdf = new PDF($fileName);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// save file
$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');
```

Here, the last line `$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');` is for saving the file. But it is not working. When I was having only `$pdf->Output()`, it was showing the pdf in browser.

I've tried `$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'D');` for downloading and it worked fine. Seems `$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');` is only not working and it shown an error `TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file: output.pdf`.

Note: there is no file permission issues

Can anyone point out the issue please.

Answer (score 26):

Try putting ob_clean(); right above $pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');

```
ob_clean();

// save file
$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');
```

if that dont work. Than you need to set a path like this:

```
$pdf->Output('yourpath/output.pdf', 'F');
```

if you dont know the absolute path try this:

```
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'output.pdf', 'F');
```

Comment: prepending $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] worked for me, thanks!

Comment: first check whether $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] contains trailing slash, if not than concat with '/' before filename

Answer (score 9):

In the 'include/tcpdf_static.php' file about 2435 line in the static function 'fopenLocal' if I delete the complete 'if statement'... works fine.

```
public static function fopenLocal($filename, $mode) {
    /*if (strpos($filename, '://') === false) {
        $filename = 'file://'.$filename;
    } elseif (strpos($filename, 'file://') !== 0) {
        return false;
    }*/
    return fopen($filename, $mode);
}
```

Comment: nice find, works!

Comment: In TCPDF Version 6.6.5  same file but line 1806+

Answer (score 7):

You have to put the full path instead of relative one, example of usage with__DIR__:

```
 $pdf->Output(__DIR__."/../invoices/invoice_".date('d-M-Y').".pdf", 'F');
```

Answer (score 5):

this is a tip for laravel programmers who using tcpdf
if you want to save pdf to your public directory, just use this:

`PDF::Output(public_path('/uploads/pdf/hello_world.pdf'),'F');`

Answer (score 4):

the issue is caused by file's path. I get this fixed by changing `$pdf->Output('output.pdf', 'F');` to absolute path `$pdf->Output('/var/www/yourdomain/output.pdf', 'F');`

Comment: I can confirm that implementing this worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I found that this error was also caused by too many images. I was trying to create a PDF with 186 images and got this error. I tried all the options above and still got this error. I then reducing the images (and did a test with 100 images) PDF created ok. Increase the number of images again and got the error again.

Answer (score 1):

Give your directory permission where you want to store your `output.pdf` file

```
chmod -R 0777 /yourdirectory
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the folder permissions as well. Because i have the same issue and i resolve it by changing the folder permissions.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that file **sample.pdf** is not open anywhere when you run script. if it's open somewhere else then TCPDF can't open it.

Answer (score 0):

I having the same issue, but for my case to solve this following issue was declare the system temporary directory on XAMPP.

`sys_temp_dir = /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/`

Answer (score 0):

en `Output`
cambiar de :

```
 $f = TCPDF_STATIC::fopenLocal($name, 'wb');
```

a:

```
$f = fopen($name, 'wb');
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this cost me like an hour:
Make sure the folder exists and that you use the full path to the file.

TCPDF doesn't seem to create folders.

```php
$year = date('Y');
$folder = __DIR__ . "/../invoices/$date";

if (!is_dir($folder)) {
    mkdir($folder, 0777, true);
}

$pdf->Output("$folder/output.pdf", 'F');
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe your file was opened by another application

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/a/54129439/2227743